# \overrightarrow with garamond: gap in the arrow

Tags: mathdesign

Typesetting `$\overrightarrow{OQ}$` yields a very unpleasant gap in the arrow when used with garamond. Here's a minimal working example that shows the problem. It looks okay without the garamond line.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[garamond]{mathdesign}    
\begin{document}
\[\overrightarrow{OQ}.\]
\end{document}
```

This is clearly an unwanted feature. Is it possible to fix this? (discarding garamond is not an option, I've already typeset and printed several hundreds of pages with it, and I want uniformity in my documents for my students).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem is that the minus sign and the arrow in the math font that's used with the `garamond` option is shorter than usual and this breaks `\rightarrowfill` that's used in `\overrightarrow`.

You should repair the glitch by redefining `\rightarrowfill`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[garamond]{mathdesign}

\makeatletter
\def\rightarrowfill{%
  $\m@th\smash-\mkern-9mu
  \cleaders\hbox{$\mkern-2mu\smash-\mkern-2mu$}\hfill
  \mkern-9mu\mathord\rightarrow$}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
$\overrightarrow{OQ}$

\makebox[1.0em]{\rightarrowfill}
\makebox[1.1em]{\rightarrowfill}
\makebox[1.2em]{\rightarrowfill}
\makebox[1.3em]{\rightarrowfill}
\makebox[1.4em]{\rightarrowfill}
\makebox[1.5em]{\rightarrowfill}
\makebox[1.6em]{\rightarrowfill}

\makebox[1.7em]{\rightarrowfill}
\makebox[1.8em]{\rightarrowfill}
\makebox[1.9em]{\rightarrowfill}
\makebox[2.0em]{\rightarrowfill}
\makebox[2.1em]{\rightarrowfill}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Using `amsmath` (which is implicitly loaded by `amsart` and `amsbook`) the patch should also be to `\arrowfill@`; it's simpler to use `etoolbox`:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd\arrowfill@{-7mu}{-9mu}{}{}
\patchcmd\arrowfill@{-7mu}{-9mu}{}{}
\patchcmd\rightarrowfill{-7mu}{-9mu}{}{}
\patchcmd\rightarrowfill{-7mu}{-9mu}{}{}
\makeatother
```

Comment: Thanks so much, it works fine! Well, in fact I'm using the amsbook class, which uses `\rightarrowfill@` instead of `\rightarrowfill`... so I redefined `\overrightarrow` as found in `base/fontmath.ltx` and with your fix it seems to work perfectly!

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf I've added the patch for `amsmath`

Comment: fantastic! I'm now using your patch for `amsmath`, it's much nicer than my solution. Thanks a lot!